# Decode a hex string into Chinese characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a hex code: %E7%B5%99.
I want to convert it into Chinese characters.

```
print ("%E7%B5%99".decode('utf-8'))
```

This doesn't seem to work.

It should give the answer: 絙

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "unquote" the percent encoded string first. Then decode from UTF8:

```
>>> s = "%E7%B5%99"
>>> print urllib.unquote(s).decode('utf8')
絙
```